# iOS 13 Mail App - Flag Only A Specific Message In A Conversation When Using Gmail?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, gmail, mobile-mail

I've noticed that with iOS, when I flag an e-mail message with Mail, every message in the conversation gets flagged.  If I flag a message on my phone and then login to Gmail on my computer, I might have multiple flags (one for every message in the conversation).

How do I change the config so that only the message I specifically flagged in Mail is flagged within Gmail?

Comment: Are you sure you actually went inside the conversation thread and flagged that email? I just tested it and only the email was flagged (starred), not the whole conversation. [iOS 13.3]